# Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held

Tags: android

Whenever I run my application and turns off/on the Wifi Connection. The application is creating a socket connectivity over TCP (using Wifi Connection). 
This is a what I receives after sometime. This is not even throwing any exception to look over!

Are these logs readable? If so can someone guide me through.

```
A/nt.ngtech.co.u: runtime.cc:558] Runtime aborting...
    runtime.cc:558] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
    runtime.cc:558] All threads:
    runtime.cc:558] DALVIK THREADS (59):
    runtime.cc:558] "FinalizerDaemon" prio=5 tid=7 Runnable
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12ec0340 self=0x777a7fb800
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27635 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7770d594f0
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=R schedstat=( 83892703 4272710 25 ) utm=6 stm=1 core=7 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0x7770c56000-0x7770c58000 stackSize=1041KB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 00000000003c7324  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+220)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 0000000000495d80  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+352)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 00000000004afd1c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+844)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 00000000004a8a5c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+476)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #04 pc 00000000004a7eac  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+1036)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #05 pc 000000000046a9d0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+392)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #06 pc 0000000000008d2c  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+724)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #07 pc 00000000002e8858  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1656)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #08 pc 00000000002e89cc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+108)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #09 pc 00000000000fd5f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+144)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #10 pc 0000000000103858  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::CheckFieldAccess(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, _jobject*, _jfieldID*, bool, art::Primitive::Type)+608)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #11 pc 0000000000102ec0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::GetField(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jfieldID*, bool, art::Primitive::Type)+736)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #12 pc 00000000000ee798  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::GetIntField(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jfieldID*)+48)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #13 pc 000000000001e270  /system/lib64/libopenjdk.so (FileDispatcherImpl_preClose0+24)
    runtime.cc:558]   at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.preClose0(Native method)
    runtime.cc:558]   at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.preClose(SocketDispatcher.java:69)
    runtime.cc:558]   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.implCloseSelectableChannel(SocketChannelImpl.java:885)
    runtime.cc:558]   - locked <0x0222ac46> (a java.lang.Object)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.implCloseChannel(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:234)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:116)
    runtime.cc:558]   - locked <0x0d64de07> (a java.lang.Object)
    runtime.cc:558]   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finalize(SocketChannelImpl.java:939)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:250)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:237)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x75343a18 self=0x777a614c00
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27624 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7800123548
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=S schedstat=( 2143157169 124172039 1653 ) utm=198 stm=15 core=7 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0x7fc262f000-0x7fc2631000 stackSize=8MB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __switch_to+0xac/0xb8
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_epoll_wait+0x254/0x360
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_epoll_pwait+0xf4/0x154
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000006f660  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 00000000000141c0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+144)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 000000000001408c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+60)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 0000000000120ddc  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+44)
    runtime.cc:558]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
    runtime.cc:558]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
    runtime.cc:558]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
    runtime.cc:558]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
    runtime.cc:558]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    runtime.cc:558]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Native
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec0000 self=0x7773e0e000
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27631 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x777414a4f0
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=S schedstat=( 555110330 77023228 943 ) utm=42 stm=12 core=5 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0x777404c000-0x777404e000 stackSize=1021KB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __switch_to+0xac/0xb8
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xc4/0x12c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe8/0x2d0
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: do_futex+0xf8/0x1408
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_futex+0x144/0x19c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000001ed2c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 00000000000d7424  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 00000000004b1594  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPool::GetTask(art::Thread*)+260)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 00000000004b0aec  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+124)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #04 pc 00000000004b059c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+148)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #05 pc 0000000000083194  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #06 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
    runtime.cc:558]   (no managed stack frames)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] "Signal Catcher" prio=5 tid=3 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec0088 self=0x777a616400
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27632 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7773dff4f0
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=S schedstat=( 307865 36719 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0x7773d04000-0x7773d06000 stackSize=1009KB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __switch_to+0xac/0xb8
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: do_sigtimedwait+0x148/0x324
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_rt_sigtimedwait+0xf0/0x150
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000006f840  /system/lib64/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+8)
A/nt.ngtech.co.u: runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 000000000002db18  /system/lib64/libc.so (sigwait+64)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 0000000000483a90  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::WaitForSignal(art::Thread*, art::SignalSet&)+416)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 0000000000482430  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+272)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #04 pc 0000000000083194  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #05 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
    runtime.cc:558]   (no managed stack frames)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] "ADB-JDWP Connection Control Thread" prio=5 tid=4 WaitingInMainDebuggerLoop
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec0110 self=0x7773e15800
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27633 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7770f5d4f0
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=S schedstat=( 2696039 1448078 21 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=6 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0x7770e62000-0x7770e64000 stackSize=1009KB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __switch_to+0xac/0xb8
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: do_sys_poll+0x2c4/0x570
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_ppoll+0x190/0x238
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000006f780  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ppoll+8)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 000000000002b718  /system/lib64/libc.so (poll+88)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 0000000000006cd0  /system/lib64/libadbconnection.so (adbconnection::AdbConnectionState::RunPollLoop(art::Thread*)+816)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 000000000000527c  /system/lib64/libadbconnection.so (adbconnection::CallbackFunction(void*)+1060)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #04 pc 0000000000083194  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #05 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
    runtime.cc:558]   (no managed stack frames)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] "HeapTaskDaemon" prio=5 tid=5 WaitingForTaskProcessor
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec1b80 self=0x7772497400
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27637 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x77657b04f0
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=S schedstat=( 159716356 26711247 156 ) utm=13 stm=2 core=5 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0x77656ad000-0x77656af000 stackSize=1041KB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __switch_to+0xac/0xb8
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xc4/0x12c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe8/0x2d0
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: do_futex+0xf8/0x1408
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_futex+0x144/0x19c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000001ed30  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+32)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 00000000000d7850  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::TimedWait(art::Thread*, long, int)+168)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 000000000022f7ac  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::GetTask(art::Thread*)+476)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 0000000000230040  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*)+96)
    runtime.cc:558]   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:475)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] "ReferenceQueueDaemon" prio=5 tid=6 Waiting
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec01d8 self=0x777a7fac00
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27634 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7770e5f4f0
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=S schedstat=( 14104374 3751146 27 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=4 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0x7770d5c000-0x7770d5e000 stackSize=1041KB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __switch_to+0xac/0xb8
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xc4/0x12c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe8/0x2d0
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: do_futex+0xf8/0x1408
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_futex+0x144/0x19c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000001ed2c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 00000000000d7424  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 00000000003c2860  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+640)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 00000000003c4324  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, art::mirror::Object*, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+428)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
    runtime.cc:558]   - waiting on <0x0002db34> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:178)
    runtime.cc:558]   - locked <0x0002db34> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] "FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" prio=5 tid=8 Sleeping
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec0688 self=0x7772496800
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27636 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x77658b64f0
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=S schedstat=( 529427 8084845 11 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=4 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0x77657b3000-0x77657b5000 stackSize=1041KB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __switch_to+0xac/0xb8
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xc4/0x12c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe8/0x2d0
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: do_futex+0xf8/0x1408
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_futex+0x144/0x19c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000001ed30  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+32)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 00000000000d7850  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::TimedWait(art::Thread*, long, int)+168)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 00000000003c2874  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+660)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 00000000003c4324  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, art::mirror::Object*, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+428)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native method)
    runtime.cc:558]   - sleeping on <0x0e395d5d> (a java.lang.Object)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:373)
    runtime.cc:558]   - locked <0x0e395d5d> (a java.lang.Object)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:314)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepFor(Daemons.java:342)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForFinalization(Daemons.java:364)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:281)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] "Binder:27624_1" prio=5 tid=9 Native
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec0920 self=0x77725db000
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27638 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x77655ac4f0
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=S schedstat=( 36031823 9998179 123 ) utm=3 stm=0 core=5 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0x77654b1000-0x77654b3000 stackSize=1009KB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __switch_to+0xac/0xb8
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: binder_ioctl_write_read+0x2df0/0x391c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: binder_ioctl+0x1d0/0x7ec
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x434/0x884
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x88/0x94
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000006f74c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 0000000000029168  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+136)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 000000000005a844  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+260)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 000000000005aa20  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+24)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #04 pc 000000000005b174  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+60)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #05 pc 000000000007bc20  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #06 pc 000000000000fb80  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #07 pc 00000000000b4a04  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #08 pc 0000000000083194  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #09 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
    runtime.cc:558]   (no managed stack frames)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] "Binder:27624_2" prio=5 tid=10 Native
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec09b8 self=0x7773e39000
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27639 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x77654ae4f0
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=S schedstat=( 59678635 21620415 196 ) utm=5 stm=0 core=4 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0x77653b3000-0x77653b5000 stackSize=1009KB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __switch_to+0xac/0xb8
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: binder_ioctl_write_read+0x2df0/0x391c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: binder_ioctl+0x1d0/0x7ec
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x434/0x884
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x88/0x94
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000006f74c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 0000000000029168  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+136)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 000000000005a844  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+260)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 000000000005aa20  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+24)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #04 pc 000000000005b174  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+60)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #05 pc 000000000007bc20  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #06 pc 000000000000fb80  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #07 pc 00000000000b4a04  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #08 pc 0000000000083194  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #09 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
    runtime.cc:558]   (no managed stack frames)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] "Binder:27624_3" prio=5 tid=11 Native
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec0a70 self=0x777a6eb800
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27643 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x77653b04f0
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=S schedstat=( 94949944 5117917 281 ) utm=7 stm=1 core=5 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0x77652b5000-0x77652b7000 stackSize=1009KB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __switch_to+0xac/0xb8
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: binder_ioctl_write_read+0x2df0/0x391c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: binder_ioctl+0x1d0/0x7ec
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x434/0x884
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x88/0x94
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000006f74c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 0000000000029168  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+136)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 000000000005a844  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+260)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 000000000005aa20  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+24)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #04 pc 000000000005b174  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+60)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #05 pc 000000000007bc20  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #06 pc 000000000000fb80  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #07 pc 00000000000b4a04  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #08 pc 0000000000083194  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #09 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
    runtime.cc:558]   (no managed stack frames)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] "Profile Saver" prio=5 tid=12 Native
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x13283d08 self=0x7773e40800
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27647 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x77643ff4f0
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=S schedstat=( 4027809 768229 39 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=5 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0x7764304000-0x7764306000 stackSize=1009KB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __switch_to+0xac/0xb8
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xc4/0x12c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe8/0x2d0
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: do_futex+0xf8/0x1408
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_futex+0x144/0x19c
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000001ed30  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+32)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 00000000000d7850  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::TimedWait(art::Thread*, long, int)+168)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 000000000032625c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ProfileSaver::Run()+588)
A/nt.ngtech.co.u: runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
    runtime.cc:558]   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
A/nt.ngtech.co.u: runtime.cc:558]   kernel: do_futex+0xf8/0x1408
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000006f660  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 000000000001ed2c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
A/nt.ngtech.co.u: runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x13080618 self=0x7770accc00
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe8/0x2d0
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=27712 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7760a694f0
    runtime.cc:558]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
A/nt.ngtech.co.u: runtime.cc:558]   - waiting on <0x0b3325da> (a java.lang.Object)
A/nt.ngtech.co.u: runtime.cc:558]   native: #51 pc 000000000025b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
A/nt.ngtech.co.u: runtime.cc:558]   native: #66 pc 000000000054f294  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #77 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
    runtime.cc:566]   native: #25 pc 000000000027c350  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
    runtime.cc:566]   native: #41 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2495989291+496)
    runtime.cc:566]   native: #65 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2495989291+496)
    runtime.cc:566]   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finalize(SocketChannelImpl.java:939)
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 27635 (FinalizerDaemon), pid 27624 (nt.ngtech.co.uk)
```

Comment: I was also facing the same issue however I found the cause. And it was **pro-guard** rules. I ended up disabling `minifyEnabled`.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher Thanks for this update. Yes I am using pro-guard rules for my app. I will try making your suggested change, and will update result here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

add this line to your android/app/build.gradle :-
`android { def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false .... }`

Comment: Thank you @makeItEasy, +1 for saving my day